# Understanding function call in element directives in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I was going through angular js docs and trying to understand following piece of code:-

```
<div ng-app="choreApp">
  <div ng-controller="ChoreCtrl">
    <kid done="logChore(chore)"></kid>
        </div>
</div>

 app.controller("ChoreCtrl", function($scope){
 $scope.logChore = function(chore){
 alert(chore + " is done!");
 };
 });

 app.directive("kid", function() {
 return {
   restrict: "E",
   scope: {
    done: "&"
  },
template: '<input type="text" ng-model="chore">' +
  '{{chore}}' +
  '<div class="button" ng-click="done({chore: chore})">I\'m done</div>'
  };
});
```

I went through the documents at least dozen times but still not convinced how {core: core} is working and how is the function logChore(core) invoked.

Can someone help me understand how above is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's explained in [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-):

> & or &attr - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<widget my-attr="count = count + value">` and widget definition of `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }`, then isolate scope property `localFn` will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression. **Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope, this can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment(amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the localFn as `localFn({amount: 22})`**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

Its the way how `expression` works using `&` while we want to pass function to directive, As you can see you have `done="logChore(chore)"` done attribute which passes `logChore` method which has `chore` parameter.

When you want to call it from directive scope, due to `done: "&"` inside directive isolated scope, you have access to done method using `scope.done`. As it also having one parameter which name is `chore` which you specified in directive element. For passing value of function parameter using JSON format like `{chore: chore}` where 1st `chore` is method parameter, the other part after `:` is nothing but `chore` which is `ng-model` value.

Basically the the function call depends on what you specified in `done` attribute of your directive element.

`done="logChore(myChore)"` then it call from directive would be `done({ myChore: chore})`